# neo4j generate unique id for existing node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I had the graphical database created a while ago and I found that my Person nodes does not have an ID. Is it possible to generate an unique id for the existing nodes? I see when I use neo4j browser, there is an auto generated ID for graph view but the ID is not in the database.

Let me know if a Cypher query can do something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WHERE NOT p.id
SET p.id = AUTO_GEN_ID
RETURN p
```

so the new nodes would be modified?

Answer (score 4):

All nodes have an automatically-generated "native ID" (that can be obtained via the [ID](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) function), but that native ID can be re-used for another node if the original node is deleted. To avoid confusion, it is best practice to add your own property (e.g., `id`, or `uuid`) if you need a unique ID.

You can use [apoc.create.uuid](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/uuid/#auto-uuid) to create a UUID. For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(p.id)
SET p.id = apoc.create.uuid()
RETURN p
```

The APOC library can also [automatically assign a UUID](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/uuid/#automatic-uuids) to a given property when a node with a specified label is created.

###### Neo4j 5.x+

`apoc.create.uuid()` was deprecated in Neo4j 5.0, and replaced by the Cypher function [randomUUID()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-randomuuid)

Comment: The `apoc.create.uuid` function has been deprecated. You can now use the Neo4j `randomUUID()` function directly instead

Comment: @fcrozatier Thanks. I added the info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass and 'unique' id via the language that you are using, just lookup uuid for you technology.

to be 100% sure that the codes are unique you have to pre-generate them or have counter that is thread-safe.